# Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find "libstlport_shared.so

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlcipher-android

I am very new to SQL Cipher. I read many stuff and implemented SQLCipher into my project.

I have put below JAR files into **app/src/libs**

- commons-codec.jar
- guava-r09.jar
- sqlcipher.jar
- sqlcipher-javadoc

I have put below file into **app/src/main/assets**

- icudt46l.zip

I have put below file into **app/src/main/jniLibs**

1. **In Folder:** armeabi

   - libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
   - libsqlcipher_android.so
   - libstlport_shared.so
2. **In Folder:** armeabi-v7a

   - libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
   - libsqlcipher_android.so
   - libstlport_shared.so
3. **In Folder:** x86

   - libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
   - libsqlcipher_android.so
   - libstlport_shared.so

Below my gradle file in android studio.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.com.sqlcipher"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

After this, i run my application and it gets crash every time with below error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/abc.com.sqlcipher-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/abc.com.sqlcipher-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblibstlport_shared.so"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 4 to 5 hours, i got the solution from one of my friend.

Write below code into **build.gradle** file before **android{}** block.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}
```

Write below line into **dependencies {}** block.

```
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:sqlcipher-for-android:3.3.1'
```

Now you Sync your project then you can use **SQL-Cipher** Database into your application eaisly.

Comment: Still getting error, and i am using this lib for sqlcipher 
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.4.0@aar'

Comment: Hi so can you tell me that we need to with sqlcipher.jar do we need to remove it and import all class of commonsware ?

Comment: @NikunjPatel i do not have idea about it. but you can ask question here https://discuss.zetetic.net/

Comment: No, but you have implemented so I want idea..so Logically so file I think need to remove and that jar also need to remove and then need to check with Commonsware.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. I am using: compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar' but still getting that error.